# How to access the Request object in a custom exception handler in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, rest, exception, servicestack

I want to register a custom exception handler in ServiceStack. The wiki at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling says:

```
this.ServiceExceptionHandler = (request, exception) => {
    //log your exceptions here
    ...
    //call default exception handler or prepare your own custom response
    return DtoUtils.HandleException(this, request, exception);
};
```

But in my exception handler the `request` argument is not the Request object, but rather the `Service` that threw the exception (at least what I can tell from the debugger). Casting `request` to `IHttpRequest` fails with an InvalidCast exception. Since the `Request`/`Response` members of `Service` are protected, I cannot access the request from within my exception handler.

What to do to access the Request? In particular, I need to access the `Content-Type` and the list of accepted languages that were send as headers in the request.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the source, it looks like `request` should be the request dto, but if you need  more than that, you can create your own `ServiceRunner<T>`, and then you will get the `IRequestContext` as well, which has a `ContentType` property.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#fine-grain-error-handling-using-the-new-apis-servicerunner

Edit, a bit more info:

When you overwrite `HandleException`, you can return an `HttpError`, which will allow you to set things like headers and a `ResponseStatus` etc.

Comment: Yes, request is the original requestDto, not the service, my bad. The `ServiceRunner` approach looks promising, but now that I have the Request i would also need access to the `Response`object - so that I can sent my custom error DTOs or HTTP return codes.